# How to install bower on centos 7

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

I am trying to install bower on centos7, after installing nodejs. To install nodejs I follows these steps

Step1: wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.30/node-v0.10.30.tar.gz

Step2: tar xzvf node-v* && cd node-v*

Step3: sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++

Step4: ./configure

Step5: make

Step6: sudo make install

Step7: node --version

I had successfully installed nodejs, I follows this steps from [Install Nodejs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-a-centos-7-server#InstallNodefromtheEPELRepository)

Then install npm by running command `sudo yum install npm`.

Now I am trying to install **bower** So I run the following command 
`npm install -g bower`. **But getting the following error. Please tell me how to install bower correctly.**

```
[neelabh@localhost node-v0.12.7]$ npm install -g bower
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /home/neelabh/.npm/bower/1.4.1/package.tgz
npm ERR! Linux 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
```

/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
    npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

```
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/neelabh/Downloads/Softwares/node-v0.12.7/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 8):

try:

```
sudo yum update -y

sudo yum install -y epel-release gcc gcc-c++ git libtool-ll libtool-ltdl-devel lsof make unixODBC unixODBC-devel wget

sudo yum install -y nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel

sudo npm install -g node-gyp bower
```

Check your internet connectivity (Are you under a proxy?). It may need additional steps to solve internet issues.

Comment: This runs perfectly with one exception.  It needs a sudo at the beginning of the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Flag `-g` require running as root: `sudo npm install -g bower`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running with sudo - 
sudo npm install -g bower

Answer (score -1):

set proxy in npm config

https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy

chu pamela.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.