# How to run bower install inside a Dockerfile?

Tags: angularjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using go for the backend and angular js for the frontend of my application, and to be able to run the frontend I should run bower install first.

note: I am building my image from a centos7 base image.

I tried adding it in the docker file in the RUN command as this

```
WORKDIR ./Frontend
RUN bower install
```

I got an error:

```
/bin/sh: bower: command not found
```

does anybody knows how can I solve this?

Comment: It looks like `bower` is not installed in your docker image

Comment: @Rudis yes but how can I install it if I am using centos7 base image?

Comment: How to install bower on centos7 is describe on http://stackoverflow.com/a/32724832/1214948

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is full example how to install bower for docker with centos

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM centos

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash bower
RUN yum install -y gcc-c++ make
RUN curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
RUN yum install -y nodejs

# install bower
RUN npm install --global bower

USER bower

#this should show bower help - try to use install instead
RUN bower help
```

and in the building phase of this docker image you should see something like below. Its indicate (in the build phase) that you successfully installed bower.

Try to change *help* to *install* and also add your docker commands -  `WORDIR ./Frontend` etc.

```
Step 8 : RUN bower help
---> Running in 2afd81510166
Usage:
bower <command> [<args>] [<options>]
Commands:
cache                   Manage bower cache
help                    Display help information about Bower
home                    Opens a package homepage into your favorite browser
```

Answer (score 4):

you should haver a look at https://github.com/marmelab/docker-bower/blob/master/Dockerfile

I see, among other things

```
RUN apt-get install -y -qq npm

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

# install bower

RUN npm install --global bower
```

Comment: thank you I am creating my image from a centos7 base image and I don't have apt installed so I am getting apt-get command not found. do you know what should I do?

Comment: If you don't know centos, use ubuntu as base image! Centos uses "yum" as "apt-get" , should work similarly.

Answer (score 1):

First of All you need to check that bower is installed globally in your machine or not.?
Than you can install package with bower.

you can install With command :
npm install bower -g